# Работоспособность работ

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Добрый день. Помогите модифицировать предложение "По завершении работ работоспособность рабочего месте проверяет квалифицированный специалист" так, чтобы в нем не было трех однокоренных слов. 
Примечание: в рамках компании "рабочее место" - устоявшееся общепринятое обозначение компьютера и связанных с ним устройств.

Comment: Если рабочее место - это компьютер, и по-другому нельзя, то может исправность? Хотя и то, и то другое - как-то диковато звучит...

Comment: Я не думаю, что тут нужно что-либо исправлять. Все слова на своём месте и избыточности нет.

Answer (score 3):

Толковые словари вообще не знают такого слова - *работоспособность* применительно к неодушевлённым предметам (только к человеку). В БСЭ, однако, находим:

> работоспособное состояние технического устройства (изделия), состояние, при котором устройство выполняет функции в соответствии со своим назначением.

Если принятое у вас определение рабочего места включает в себя только *устройства* (без стула и стола), можно заменить так:

> По завершении работ работоспособность группы устройств проверяет квалифицированный специалист

"Работ" можно заменить по смежности: "профилактики", "ремонта"... Но тогда ради красоты стиля вы измените смысл (сузите значение), а из-за этого придётся удлинить общий текст документа и размыть понимание. Следовательно, [[@Яzz](/users/1864/%D1%8Fzz)](/users/1864/%D1%8Fzz) в своём комментарии совершенно прав: текст идеально подходит для инструкции или договора, ничего там менять не надо (вы же не стихи пишете).

===== upd =====

Упомянутая [[@Лар](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f) *исправность* кажется очень неплохим синонимом. Забавно, что в её определение входит *работоспособность* (БСЭ):

> Исправность, состояние технического устройства, при котором оно соответствует всем требованиям, обусловленным технической документацией. Исправным считается такое устройство, у которого все параметры, определяющие **работоспособность** и характеризующие его состояние и внешний вид, находятся в заданных пределах...

А в определении работоспособности (в той же БСЭ) указано:

> [...] Устройство работоспособно, если его основные параметры находятся в пределах, предусмотренных технической документацией [...] Если все параметры устройства находятся в установленных пределах, то оно считается **исправным**

Так что в вашем контексте **исправность** будет даже надёжней (как более сильное требование), чем *работоспособность*.

Answer (score 2):

Работоспособность - атрибут работника, а не его места.
У рабочего места есть функциональность (тоже не фонтан, но прижилось), эргономичность, комфортность, гигиеничность и проч. - в зависимости от направленности изучения.

Честно говоря, воспринял эту "работоспособность рабочего места" как фразу из серии "нарочно не придумаешь", всерьёз её рассматривать нельзя.

Коль скоро на предприятии сложилась своя терминология, то не будет большим грехом употребить и "однокоренное" слово, поскольку оно используется в качестве вновь определяемого термина. 
Но в таком случае работоспособность становится синонимом исправности, чем и можно воспользоваться. 
Кстати, во времена царя Гороха, был такой термин - АРМ, это про него?

Answer (score 1):

*По завершению обслуживания техники (или что они там делают), правильность функционирования рабочего места проверяет квалифицированный специалист*

Хотя, как я и писал ранее в комментарии, можно оставить и в изначальном виде.